# Oracle SQL. CREATE DIRECTORY pass path as a paramiter of Java stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm new to Oracle, and I would like to create DIRECTORY object in my Java stored procedure, to which I pass the path of this directory. So I go with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
 AND compile JAVA source named "Test0"
 AS
  import java.io.*;
   import java.sql.*;
 class Test0 {
     public static void Load(String dctry) throws SQLException {
     System.out.println(dctry);
     #sql { CREATE DIRECTORY IMG_DIR_TMP AS :dctry};
    }
  }
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_0_sp(dctry IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'Test0.Load(java.lang.String)';
/

begin
test_0_sp('/home/oracle/Desktop/sql/images');
end;
```

And I get:

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLException: ORA-01780: string literal required
```

I also tried it even as normal PL/SQL block, but I fail:

```
declare
direct varchar2(50);
begin
direct := '/home/oracle/Desktop/sql/images';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(direct);
CREATE DIRECTORY IMG_DIR_TMP AS :direct;
end;

Bind Variable "direct" is NOT DECLARED
```

I would really appreciate your help, especially with the first Java stored Procedure.
Bless ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, maybe it'll be useful someday for someone.

**Java SP**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
 AND compile JAVA source named "Test0"
 AS
  import java.io.*;
   import java.sql.*;
 class Test0 {
     public static void Load(String dctry) throws SQLException {
     System.out.println(dctry);
     String qry = "CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY IMG_DIR_TMP AS '" + dctry + "'";
      System.out.println(qry);
      #sql { 
            begin
              execute immediate :qry;
            end;
      };
    }
  }
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_0_sp(dctry IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'Test0.Load(java.lang.String)';
/

begin
test_0_sp('/home/oracle/Desktop/sql/images');
end;
```

**PL/SQL block**

```
declare
direct varchar2(100);
qry varchar2(200);
begin
direct := '/home/oracle/Desktop/sql/images';
qry := q'[CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY IMG_DIR_TMP AS ']'||direct||q'[;']';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(qry);
execute immediate qry;
end;
```

Greetings.